# How to move Data Which came from graphql to redux/toolkit's state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graph, apollo, redux-toolkit

My problem is like so. I have data which comes from node backend. Currently it is stored in functional component using useQuery hook. Now I want to take this data and store it to Reduxt/toolkit's state. What to do to accomplish that.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

export default function Product() {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_PRODUCTS);
  if (!loading && !error) {
    //getting produch
  }

  return <>{data}</>;
}
```

and this is the redux/toolkit state

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import Product from "../../components/Product";


const initialState = {
  cartItems: [], // I want to inser Here
  amount: 0,
  total: 0,
  isLoading: true,
};

const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: "cart",
  initialState,
});

//console.log(cartSlice);
export default cartSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: please delete this question I have already figuru out